# Controller com repository, Ioc e DI

Tags: c#, mvc, controller, ioc

Estou tentando implementar  a gravação dos dados das minhas views,sendo que to tendo dúvidas quanto a forma de instanciar meu `Usuario` repositório na minha *controller*, mesmo usando exemplos de  injeção de dependência, porque no construtor do meu usuário repositório ele espera receber uma interface do meu contexto.

Como eu posso fazer na minha *controller* para ter acesso aos métodos `add`, `savechanges` e etc.

Meu usuário Repositório:

```
RepositoryBase<Usuario>, IUsuarioRepository
{
    public UsuarioRepository(ILetsPartyContext context)
        : base(context)
    {

    }

}
```

Como tentei implementar porém não funcionou.

```
public ILetsPartyContext _Context;

   public UsuarioController(ILetsPartyContext Context)
    {
      _Context = Context;
    }


    UsuarioRepository rep = new UsuarioRepository(_Context);
```

Answer (score 1):

O ideal, é que você tenha um modo de resolver a dependência de seus tipos. Por exemplo, para que seu tipo `UsuarioRepository` seja resolvido, este depende de `ILetsPartyContext`, que também deve ser resolvido.

Dado que você tem um `container` um inversão de controle  (`IoC` - sigla do inglês `inversion of control`), você poderia fazer seu `Controller` depender de seu repositório de usuários e o repositório depender deste contexto. Por exemplo:

```
public class UsuarioRepositorio : IUsuarioRepositorio
{
   private readonly ILetsPartyContext _context = null;

   public UsuarioRepositorio(ILetsPartyContext context)
   {
      _context = context;
   }

   // outros métodos...
}
```

e seu controller:

```
public class UsuarioController : Controller
{
   private readonly IUsuarioRepositorio _usuarioRepositorio = null;

   public UsuarioController(IUsuarioRepositorio usuarioRepositorio)
   {
      _usuarioRepositorio = usuarioRepositorio;
   }

   // outros métodos...
}
```

Compartilhe como você está fazendo para resolver estas dependências, qual container está usando e como está fazendo o `setup` deste.

Comment: Felipe, no caso eu estou tendo duvidas da maneira correta de injetar uma dependecia na minha controller de forma que eu consiga utilizar os metodos de insercao da minha usuariorepositorio e utilizar o savechanges do meu contexto.

Answer (score 0):

Felipe, no caso eu estou tendo duvidas da maneira correta de injetar uma dependecia na minha controller de forma que eu consiga utilizar os metodos de insercao da minha usuariorepositorio e utilizar o savechanges do meu contexto.
 No caso estou  habituado com a utilizacao de repositorios sem o conceito de IoC e DI,onde o que desejo fazer e:

public class ClientesController : Controller

```
   {
    // Troca o contexto
    //private BancoContexto db = new BancoContexto();
    private readonly ClienteRepositorio repCli = new ClienteRepositorio();}
```

de forma que eu consiga:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="ClienteID,Nome,CNPJ,Endereco,Telefone,Ativo")] Cliente cliente)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //db.Cliente.Add(cliente);
            repCli.Adicionar(cliente);

            //db.SaveChanges();
            repCli.SalvarTodos();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(cliente);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace LetsParty.Infra.Data.Context
```

{
    public class LetsPartyContext : DbContext, ILetsPartyContext
    {
        public LetsPartyContext() : base("TCCBanco")
        {

```
    }
    public LetsPartyContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {

    }

    public DbContext Context
    {
        get
        {
            return this;
        }
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        this.SaveChanges();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UsuarioDbMapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FornecedorMapping());

    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<LetsParty.Domain.Model.Atores.Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }

}
```

}